# Xbox live gold has expired, Can the game that was previously purchased and downloaded continue to play?

Tags: xbox-one

My Xbox Live is about to expire, I don't want to renew it, so can I continue playing with the previous download game?

Comment: In addition to the answers you won't be able to use any online features of the games themselves such as online multiplayer.

Answer (score 13):

From the official microsoft faq (I guess it's the same as when the subscription expires):

> What happens to my Games with Gold games if I cancel my Xbox Live Gold
>   subscription?
>
> On **Xbox One**, you’ll no longer be able to access your Games with Gold
>   titles if you cancel your subscription. However, if you decide to
>   renew your subscription at any time, you’ll be able to access and play
>   your previously redeemed Games with Gold titles again.
>
> On **Xbox 360**, any Games with Gold titles that you redeem as an Xbox
>   Live Gold member are yours to keep, regardless of whether you continue
>   your subscription.

source: https://support.xbox.com/en-US/my-account/xbox-live-membership/games-with-gold-faq

Comment: I can confirm this for Xbox One, as I've stopped renewing my Gold subscription after I stopped playing Xbox One. When I returned to play some of the games I got for free, I was told I needed a valid subscription to do that.

Comment: He is asking about purchased games. Aren't Gold games those you get for "free" with the subscription?

Comment: This is answering the wrong question. This is answering whether the OP can continue playing games they got free with their gold membership - the OP is actually asking about games they *purchased* while they had a gold membership.

Comment: I don't see the OP saying he purchased any game.. he only said "downloaded" and I got that as "downloaded" for free. If this isn't answering the OP question I'd sugget the OP to edit it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no.

Games that you have bought or were gifted are yours and are not affected by your subscription. However, some game functionality might not be available. That depends on the game.

Games that you have had access through one of the subscriptions features, be it Games with Gold or Xbox Game Pass, games will no longer be playable.

Answer (score 0):

Put your console offline or unhook it from the internet before your gold is up and you can still play them enjoy the loop hole

Comment: That won't work on Xbox one , you have to go online after x-days